# MySQL insert multiple records from select please view code

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I want to bring this information to insert multiple records from select

**This  all FORM**

```
<?php
session_start();
//PUT THIS HEADER ON TOP OF EACH UNIQUE PAGE
if(!isset($_SESSION['id_user'])){
  header("location:../index.php");
  header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
}
include "config.php";

$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM vn_order order by id_vn_order desc ";
$objQuery = mysqli_query($mysqli,$strSQL);
$sqlus = "SELECT * FROM vn_user WHERE id_user = '".$_SESSION['id_user']."' ";
$objQu = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sqlus);
$objResult = mysqli_fetch_array($objQu);

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Limitless - Responsive Web Application Kit by Eugene Kopyov</title>

  <!-- Global stylesheets -->


 <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kanit&subset=thai,latin' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
 <link href="assets/css/icons/icomoon/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 <link href="assets/css/core.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 <link href="assets/css/components.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 <link href="assets/css/colors.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 <link href="assets/css/sweet-alert.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/alert/sweet-alert.js"></script>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="respond.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
body {
  font-family: 'Kanit', sans-serif;
  }
  </style>

</head>
<body onLoad="setPostBack();">

<?php require_once("inc/header_menu.php") ?>
          <!-- /user menu -->


         <?php require_once("inc/menu.php") ?>


      <!-- Main content -->
      <div class="content-wrapper">

        <!-- Content area -->
        <div class="content">

          <!-- Basic datatable -->
          <div class="panel panel-flat">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h5 class="panel-title">จองรถตู้</h5>
              <div class="heading-elements">
                <ul class="icons-list">
                  <li><a data-action="collapse"></a></li>
                  <li><a data-action="reload"></a></li>
                  <li><a data-action="close"></a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="panel-body">

            </div>
            <form role="form" action="dorent.php" method="post" onSubmit="return doSubmit();">
              <input type="hidden" value="1" name="id_user"/>
              <input type="hidden" value="1" name="id_invoice"/>
              <input type="hidden" value="1" name="travellist_id"/>
              <input type="hidden" value="Approve" name="Status"/>


              <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="row">
                 <div class="col-md-6">
                  <fieldset>
                    <legend class="text-semibold"><i class="icon-reading position-left"></i> Personal details</legend>
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <label>ชื่อ</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="ชื่อ" name="rn_first_name" id="rn_first_name" value="<?php echo $objResult["firstname"];?>" readonly>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label>นามสกุล:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="นามสกุล" name="rn_last_name" id="rn_last_name" value="<?php echo $objResult["lastname"];?>"readonly>
                  </div>

                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label>E-mail</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="Email" name="" id="" value="<?php echo $objResult["email"];?>"readonly>
                      </div>

                    </div>



                   <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label>เบอร์โทรศัพท์</label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control format-phone-number" name="rn_tel" id="rn_tel" placeholder="เบอร์ติดต่อ" value="<?php echo $objResult["Tel"];?>"maxlength="10" readonly>


                      </div>

                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript">    
                $(function(){    
                  var obj_a = $("#rn_amount");
                  var obj_b = $("#data_b");  
                  // a เปลี่ยนเมื่อ keyup แล้ว b เปลี่ยน ตามเงื่อนไขค่า a  
                  obj_a.on("keyup",function(){  
                  var value_obj_a = parseInt($(this).val()); // เก็บค่า a ไว้ในตัวแปร  (parseInt คือเปลงเป็นเลข)  
                  if(value_obj_a>9){ // กำหนดเงื่อนไขให้กับค่า a  
                  obj_b.val(2); // เปลี่ยนค่า b เป้น 3              
                }else{
                obj_b.val(1); // เปลี่ยนค่า b เป็น 1 
              }
            });
                });  
              </script>        
              <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label>จำนวนวนคนที่ไป</label>
                      <input type="text" name="rn_amount" id="rn_amount" value="" class="form-control"><br>
                    </div>
                  </div>            
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                      <div class="form-group">
                                 <label class="display-block text-semibold">ประเภทรถตู้</label>

                        <select name="data_b" id="data_b" class="form-control">
                          <option value=""> Select </option>
                          <option value="1">9</option>    
                          <option value="2">13</option>
                        </select>
                      </div> 
                   </div> 
                 </div> 
               </div> 
                 <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6">

                  <legend class="text-semibold"><i class="icon-truck position-left"></i> Shipping details</legend>

                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label>วันที่จอง : (วันที่ไป)</label>
                        <input class="form-control" type="date" name="rn_gostart" id="rn_gostart">
                      </div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-6">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label>วันที่กลับ : (วันกลับ)</label>
                        <input class="form-control" type="date" name="rn_endstart" id="rn_endstart">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>


                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label>เวลาเดินทางไป</label>
                        <input class="form-control"  type="time" name="time_gostart" id="time_gostart">
                      </div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-6">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label>เวลาเดินทางกลับ</label>                        
                          <input class="form-control" type="time" name="time_endstart" id="time_endstart">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                <!-- เลือกสถานที่ท่องเที่ยว -->
                <input type="hidden" id="txtNum" value="1" size="2" />
                <table border="0" width="100%">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th>
                       <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="display-block text-semibold"> จังหวัดที่ท่องเที่ยว</label>
                            <select name="province_id[]" id="selProvince"  class="select-search">
                              <option value="">กรุณาเลือกจังหวัด</option>
                              <?php 
                              include("connect.inc.php");
                              $SelectPr="SELECT * FROM province";
                              $QueryPro=mysql_query($SelectPr);
                              while($Pro=mysql_fetch_array($QueryPro)){
                                ?>
                                <option value="<?=$Pro['province_id']?>"><?=$Pro['province_name']?></option>
                                <?php } ?>
                              </select>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </th>
                      <th>
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                              <label class="display-block text-semibold"> สถานที่ท่องเที่ยว</label>
                              <select id="selTravel" name="travel_id[]" class="select-search"><option value="">กรุณาเลือกจังหวัด</option></select>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </th>
                    <th>

                    </th>
                  </tr>
                  <tr><td><center>รายการที่เพิ่ม</center></td></tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>

                </tbody>
              </table>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <button type="button" id="btnP">เพิ่มรายการ</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>



<div class="row">
                     <div class="col-md-6">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="display-block text-semibold"> สถานที่ไปรับ</label>
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="rn_place" autocomplete="off">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label>สถานที่เพิ่มเติมระหว่างทาง</label>
                    <textarea rows="5" cols="5" class="form-control" name="vn_dtial"  placeholder="Enter your message here"></textarea>
                  </div>

                  </fieldset>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="text-right">
                <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary">Submit form <i class="icon-arrow-right14 position-right"></i></button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>


<!-- Footer -->
          <div class="footer text-muted f-xs text-center">
            &copy; 2016. <a href="#">ระบบจองรถตู้ออนไลน์</a> by ออนทัว
          </div>
          <!-- /footer -->

   </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




  <!-- Core JS files -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/plugins/loaders/pace.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/core/libraries/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/core/libraries/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/plugins/loaders/blockui.min.js"></script>
  <!-- /core JS files -->

  <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/core/libraries/jquery_ui/interactions.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/plugins/forms/selects/select2.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/pages/form_select2.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/plugins/forms/styling/uniform.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/core/app.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/pages/form_layouts.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/plugins/forms/styling/uniform.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/plugins/forms/styling/switchery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/plugins/forms/styling/switch.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/pages/form_checkboxes_radios.js"></script>




</table>
</body>
</html>
```

**This is the only required**

```
<table border="0" width="100%">  
                  <thead>  
                    <tr>  
                      <th>  
                       <div class="row">  
                        <div class="col-md-10">  
                          <div class="form-group">  
                            <label class="display-block text-semibold"> จังหวัดที่ท่องเที่ยว</label>  
                            <select name="province_id[]" id="selProvince"  class="select-search">  
                              <option value="">กรุณาเลือกจังหวัด</option>  
                              <?php   
                              include("connect.inc.php");  
                              $SelectPr="SELECT * FROM province";  
                              $QueryPro=mysql_query($SelectPr);  
                              while($Pro=mysql_fetch_array($QueryPro)){  
                                ?>  
                                <option value="<?=$Pro['province_id']?>"><?=$Pro['province_name']?></option>  
                                <?php } ?>  
                              </select>  
                            </div>  
                          </div>  
                        </div>  
                      </th>  
                      <th>  
                        <div class="row">  
                          <div class="col-md-12">  
                            <div class="form-group">  
                              <label class="display-block text-semibold"> สถานที่ท่องเที่ยว</label>  
                              <select id="selTravel" name="travel_id[]" class="select-search"><option value="">กรุณาเลือกจังหวัด</option></select>  
                            </div>  
                          </div>  
                        </div>  
                      </div>  
                    </th>  
                    <th>  

                    </th>  
                  </tr>  
                  <tr><td><center>รายการที่เพิ่ม</center></td></tr>  
                </thead>  
                <tbody>  

                </tbody>  
              </table>  
              <div class="row">  
                <div class="form-group">  
                  <div class="col-md-6">  
                    <button type="button" id="btnP">เพิ่มรายการ</button>  
                  </div>  
                </div>  
              </div>
```

FORM INSERT

```
<?php
session_start();
//PUT THIS HEADER ON TOP OF EACH UNIQUE PAGE
if(!isset($_SESSION['id_user'])){
  header("location:index.php");

}


include_once('config.php');

$id_user = $_SESSION['id_user'];
$rn_first_name = $_POST['rn_first_name'];
$rn_last_name = $_POST['rn_last_name'];
$rn_gostart = $_POST['rn_gostart'];
$rn_endstart = $_POST['rn_endstart'];
$time_gostart = $_POST['time_gostart'];
$time_endstart = $_POST['time_endstart'];
$rn_tel = $_POST['rn_tel'];
$rn_amount = $_POST['rn_amount'];
$rn_svan = $_POST['rn_svan'];
$rn_destination = $_POST['rn_destination'];
$id_invoice = $_POST['id_invoice'];
$Status = $_POST['Status'];
$vn_dtial = $_POST['vn_dtial'];
$rn_place = $_POST['rn_place'];

$travellist_id = $_POST['travellist_id'];
$province_id = $_POST['province_id'];
$travel_id = $_POST['travel_id'];

$total = $_POST['total'];


// function date
$date_go = "$rn_gostart"; //กำหนดค้นวันที่เริ่ม
$date_end = "$rn_endstart"; //กำหนดค้นวันที่กลับ
$datetime1 = new DateTime($date_go);  
$datetime2 = new DateTime($date_end);  
$datetotal = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);  
$total= $datetotal->format('%a') * 1800;  //ผลการคำนวณ


$date = "$rn_gostart"; //กำหนดค้นวันที่

$result = mysqli_query($mysqli,"select * from vn_rent where rn_gostart = '$date'");
$ckd = mysqli_num_rows($result);


if($ckd >= 3){

$msg = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>
<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign'></span> &nbsp; วันที่จองเต็มแล้ว
</div>";
}else{

  // ส่วนของการ insert
$sql = "INSERT INTO vn_rent (id_user,rn_first_name,rn_last_name,rn_gostart,rn_endstart,time_gostart,time_endstart,rn_tel,rn_amount,rn_svan,Status,vn_dtial,rn_place,rn_destination,total)
VALUES ('$id_user', '$rn_first_name',' $rn_last_name ','$rn_gostart','$rn_endstart','$time_gostart','$time_endstart','$rn_tel','$rn_amount','$rn_svan','$Status','$vn_dtial','$rn_place','$rn_destination','$total')";


//คำสั่ง insert  2 ตาราง ที่ส่งค่าไปอีกตารางแล้วนำกลับมาอัปเดท
if ($mysqli->query($sql) === TRUE) {


     $id_van = $mysqli->insert_id;
   $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO invoice 
                   (id_user,id_van) 
              VALUE($id_user,  $id_van)");


    $id_invoice = $mysqli->insert_id;
    $mysqli->query("UPDATE vn_rent  
                    SET id_invoice = '$id_invoice' 
                 WHERE id_van = $id_van");




    $msg = "<div class ='alert alert-success alert-styled-left alert-arrow-left alert-bordered'>
      จองรถตู้สำเร็จ โปรดรอการตอบรับจากทางเจ้าหน้าที่</p> เลขที่รายการจอง <span class='text-warning'>".$id_van."</span> เลขที่ใบเสร็จ <span class='text-warning'>".$id_invoice."</span>

     </div>";

     header("refresh:5; url=history_booking.php");
} 



else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $mysqli->error;
}
}


$mysqli->close();




?>
```

To put that into multiple records from select into the table travel_list

[multiple records from select](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDPDF.png)

Comment: HELP ME plase fix code